# Login Authentication by Username or by Email

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have written my own very simple authentication bundle, it's entirely based on symfony's security module. Thus in security.yml file I've got a provider with entity given along with the username field. I am able to authenticate with username, but I want to be able to login using email either...How can I do this?

I've been thinking about creating two providers - each having the same entity, but different authenticating database field.

This is how it currently looks like:

```
providers:
    acme_users:
        entity:
            class: Acme\AdminBundle\Entity\Users
            property: login
            manager_name:       ~
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple... read the Symfony2 docs:

[How to Create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)

[How to Load Security Users from the Database (the Entity Provider)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)

PS: the links refers to the current Symfony2 version (2.5)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this few months ago. Basically I created a custom user provider with my own query. You can read more about it here:
http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/symfony2-login-username-e-mail/